# Find the most flat area among a set of data

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I have a set of data, which is shown as below:

```matlab
    a =
    8.6990   19.7143
    9.0000   23.5057
    9.1761   23.4864
    9.3010   23.9191
    9.3979   23.6779
    9.4771   24.3973
    9.5441   24.2236
    9.6021   24.0232
    9.6532   23.8172
    9.6990   24.0572
    9.7404   24.1207
    9.7782   24.0674
    9.8129   24.3270
    9.8451   24.4224
    9.8751   24.3044
    9.9031   24.5555
    9.9294   24.4349
    9.9542   24.5362
    9.9777   24.5995
   10.0000   24.7651
   10.0212   24.7552
   10.0414   24.9459
   10.0607   24.8709
   10.0792   24.9778
   10.0969   25.2394
   10.1139   25.2769
   10.1303   25.2918
   10.1461   25.6177
   10.1614   25.7244
   10.1761   25.8103
   10.1903   25.8171
   10.2041   25.8302
   10.2175   26.0061
   10.2304   26.1267
   10.2430   26.3699
   10.2553   26.6046
   10.2672   26.4685
   10.2788   26.8575
   10.2900   26.9997
   10.3010   27.1243
   10.3118   27.3388
   10.3222   27.3983
   10.3324   27.4009
   10.3424   27.7036
   10.3522   27.8784
   10.3617   28.1373
   10.3711   28.4575
   10.3802   28.3749
   10.3892   28.5800
   10.3979   28.5433
   10.4065   28.8831
   10.4150   29.5981
   10.4232   28.8865
```

When I plot `Y (a(:,2)) vs X (a(:,1))`, the plot is shown as below:

[image]

My question is explained in the figure. How can I find the most flat (slop = 0) area and the corresponding Y value? Currently I have a lot sets of data, which have the same trend as shown in the Figure.

Comment: "most flat" is meaningless until you've defined your metric of flatness.  Your text states `slop = 0` [sic], but the graph does not have a net slope of 0 over the marked range.  What differentiates that range from one that differs 0.01 to the left or right?  What if the graph varies wildly within that range?  I assume these are factors in your problem, because if it were simply the greatest x-separation between identical y values, the solution is straightforward, and you would have solved it already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly find the **"MOST FLAT AREA"** with this data set. Visually it is evident the you want to find a small increment in *y* for increment in *x* (Assuming that might be true/valid for decrements as well). But my concern here is, there are more fluctuations in (overall) curve trace in that region.

Options are:

1) Find a suitable library for curve tracing and simply use it to get a smooth curve. Find the **slope** of the curve and define your **range of acceptance**. Get that/those x coordinates/values where your slope achieves acceptance.

2) Do that without smoothening.

There is really not much information to work with here.